# how to write a code to generate permutation from 1 to N

Tags: python

Hi: I am trying to write the python code to generate the permutation: to get `perm(n)`, I will insert `n` into the position from `0` to `n-1` in the result of repeating `perm(n-1) n` times.

for example, to get `perm(2)`, I will do:

1. repeat `[1]` 2 times, to get `L1 = [[1], [1]]`
2. for each list in `L1`, insert 2 in the position of 0 and 1 to get `[[1,2], [2,1]]`.

Then I get the answer.

But I have questions:

1. when I repeat the `[1]` `n=2` times, if I `use [1] * 2` I will get shallow copy. Then when I change one, the others will be changed. Is there any way to get the same result as `use [1] * 2` but not shallow copy?
2. what is the best way to do this?

The following is my code, but it does not work:

```
def perm(n):
    res = []
    if n == 1:
        res = [1]
    else:
        s = [perm(n - 1) for i in range(n)]
        s2 = [[item] for sublist in s for item in sublist]
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(len(perm(n - 1))):
                res.append(s2[i * len(perm(n - 1)) + j].insert(i, n))
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1] for i in xrange(2)]
```

This will work. Creates new lists instead of just adding references to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function that does that for you:
[itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = '123'
>>> for i in itertools.permutations(a):
...     print(i)
... 
('1', '2', '3')
('1', '3', '2')
('2', '1', '3')
('2', '3', '1')
('3', '1', '2')
('3', '2', '1')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to practice writing code myself rather than using the internal codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to repeat `[1]` then as @aa333 says, you can use `[[1] for i in xrange(2)]`.

But I think what you really want is to turn `[[1, 2], [2, 1]]` into `[[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]`.

In that case you need something like:

```
[L[:] for _ in range(n) for L in permutation_list]
```

The `[:]` makes sure you get a separate (shallow) copy of the list each time.